# Angle on text so it looks more natural on image

Tags: css

Using CSS, I'm wondering how I can make the text on this image look more like its on the actual image?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<span className="mainPicTitle">How can i make this text angle so it suits the wall?</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainPicTitle {
   font-size: 40px;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   grid-column: 1 / 4;
   grid-row: 1/1;
   margin-top: 1em;
   justify-self: center;
   font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
}
```

All suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css 3d or skew transform rules to set the text in desired angles. I made a sample snippet with large angles to show the effect you may need to set the anagles to exact ones.

More about transforms [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

```css
#wrapper{
position:relative;
}

.mainPicTitle {
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000000;
  z-index:2;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-65deg) rotateY(2deg);
}

img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span class="mainPicTitle">How can i make this text angle so it suits the wall?</span>

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyUow.png">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the CSS transform doesn't apply on inline elements. What you can do is change span to p tag and add rotate css

```
.mainPicTitle {
   font-size: 40px;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   grid-column: 1 / 4;
   grid-row: 1/1;
   margin-top: 1em;
   justify-self: center;
   font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
  transform: rotateZ(4deg);
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ashfaq_haq/pen/pooamYO

And if you really want not to change span element, then change display type of span-

```
.mainPicTitle {
   font-size: 40px;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   grid-column: 1 / 4;
   grid-row: 1/1;
   margin-top: 1em;
   justify-self: center;
   font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
   display: block;      
   transform: rotateZ(4deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to use transform to rotate your text ?

Something like :

```
.mainPicTitle{
  -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg); /* Safari prior 9.0 */
  transform: rotate(-4deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the transform prorperty

```css
.mainPicTitle{
height:350px;
width:550px;
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
padding:50px;
padding-top:20px;
transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(-30deg) rotateZ(-2deg);

}
```

```html
<div class="mainPicTitle">How can i make this text angle so it suits the wall?</div>
```